# PHP - translating an array to a map of arrays

Tags: php, arrays, dictionary

I have an array of objects - a results of some query.

It looks like this: j - number of rows returned from the table

```
result[j]->date, result[j]->user, result[j]->count
```

The PK of the table is  date+user, meaning i can have rows:

```
1.1.2016 user1 5
1.1.2016 user2 8
5.1.2016 user1 4
```

For my purpose i need to create a map that will have a number of elements = number of different dates in the previous array, so it will look like that:

```
map[j=dateX] -> array that consist of pairs (user+count) as many as i have that have this date.
```

meaning on date 1.1.2016 i will have 2 objects - (user1, 5) and (user2, 8)
and on date 5.1.2016 only one pair (user1, 4)
Is there some structure in PHP that can help me to create this "map" as there is in JAVA for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [array_map](http://php.net/array_map). Iterate over every `object` in `array` and add them to new `array` with same `key` (date). This results objects with same date to be in one `array`.

```
$map = array(); // new mapped array
array_map(function($obj) use (&$map){
    $map[$obj->date][] = $obj;
}, $arr);
```

**TEST**

```
$obj1 = new stdClass();
$obj1->date = '1.1.2016';
$obj1->user = 'user1';
$obj1->count = 5;

$obj2 = clone $obj1;
$obj2->user = 'user2';
$obj2->count = 8;

$obj3 = clone $obj1;
$obj3->date = '5.1.2016';
$obj3->count = 4;

$arr = array($obj1, $obj2, $obj3);

$map = array();
array_map(function($obj) use (&$map){
    $map[$obj->date][] = $obj;
}, $arr);

print_r($map);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [1.1.2016] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [date] => 1.1.2016
                    [user] => user1
                    [count] => 5
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [date] => 1.1.2016
                    [user] => user2
                    [count] => 8
                )

        )

    [5.1.2016] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [date] => 5.1.2016
                    [user] => user1
                    [count] => 4
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: thanks! I saw array_map but i didnt understand how to use it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create array of Associative arrays like this

```
    <?php
    //this array indicates your row.
    $array = array(
        "date" => "1.1.2016",
        "users" => array(
                  "user" => "someUser",
                   "count" => 56
                  );    
    );
    ?>
```

then you can have these rows in another array.
What i mean is nothing but your own data structure

Comment: How it will help me with the output i want? In the end i need to have a structure where i can print to a table all the (user,count) pairs for a specific date

Comment: In such a case go with this nested arrays. You can retrieve users of specific data in this nested arrays